# How to add a link in mermaid websequence diagram

Tags: jekyll, mermaid

I have a mermaid websequence diagram snippet in jekyll blog

````
```mermaid
sequenceDiagram
    actor User
    participant ABC
    User->>ABC: Hello <-- i want this to be a hyperlink to a section on the same page
````

i tried this, but doesn't work

````
```mermaid
sequenceDiagram
    actor User
    participant ABC
    User->>ABC: <a href=#somelink>Hello</a>
````

it shows the entire text as is, without converting the text `Hello` to a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue on GitHub for this. So this feature seems not available for now. https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/1279